# Countability of Gal(C/Q) and isomorphism of its subgroups

Tags: group-theory, field-theory, galois-theory, group-isomorphism, galois-extensions

Firstly, I want to know how can I prove that Gal(C/Q) is an uncountable group. Secondly how to show that the subgroup {g ϵ Gal(C/Q)| g continous} is isomorphic to Z/2. Really I don't know how to start so any clues are useful. The only time when I work with this type of Galois group was when I tried to show that Gal(R/Q) is trivial using R-homomorphisms and automorphisms.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Probably better (more accurate) to refer to the automorphism group of $\mathbb C$ over $\mathbb Q$ as just that, an automorphism group, not Galois group... since Galois groups are officially defined only for algebraic (possibly infinite) extensions, and some things about "conjugates" and such don't make the same sense in non-algebra extensions. But probably this is just a quibble with your terminology... Still, reflexes developed for algebraic extensions do not apply to non-algebraic...

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

1. Show that $\operatorname{Gal}(\overline{\Bbb Q}/\Bbb Q)$ is uncountable.
2. Show that any continuous element fixes $\Bbb R$.